# How can I apply a character limit to an element that shares a class name with multiple elements using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Say you have multiple frames with the same class name that will be dynamically created on your page which contains text of various lengths and you want to limit each frame to displaying 100 characters.  How would you make this happen?  So far I've come up with this JQuery script which isn't working.

```
$('.frame').each(function(){
var item = this.attr('id').html().text();

if (item.length > 100){
    item.trim(101, maxlength) + "...";
}
});
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to first go through each element by class, then gather each element by ID so it applies it uniquely where needed, then run the if condition to test it and trim it where needed.  This is the best I've been able to muster so far so any further help will be appreciated.  Here's the rest of the coding so you can see what I'm trying to apply it to.

CSS

```
.frame{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:20px;
  clear:both;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="frame" id="show01">
   Lorem ipsum a bunch of times which I took out to make this shorter
</div>

<div class="frame" id="show02">
   Lorem ipsum a bunch of times which I took out to make this shorter
</div>

<div class="frame" id="show03">
   Lorem ipsum a bunch of times which I took out to make this shorter
</div>

<div class="frame" id="show04">
   Lorem ipsum a bunch of times which I took out to make this shorter
</div>

<div class="frame" id="show05">
   Lorem ipsum a bunch of times which I took out to make this shorter
</div>

<div class="frame" id="show06">
   Lorem ipsum a bunch of times which I took out to make this shorter
</div>
```

Also if someone can tell me how to add a JSfiddle I'll include that in the post as well if needed.  Since they updated I've been having a hard time figuring out how to work with it, I JUST figured out how to add the Jquery library to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something like `substring()` to get your visible string.

The `substring()` method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.

This method extracts the characters in a string between `"start"` and `"end"`, not including `"end"` itself.

**Modified jQuery Block:**

```
$('.frame').each(function(){
    var limit = 100;
    var item = $(this).text(); //it is return a string

    if (item.length > limit){
        $(this).text(item.substring(0, (limit + 1)) + "...");
    }else{
        $(this).text(item);
    }
});
```

This is how you can figure out how to work with it. If you want to show the hidden text like as `read more` then use some technique to achieve it. It will be very easy for now.

Comment: ok this isn't working either, yet I'm not getting any errors in my console.

Comment: I said I WASN'T getting any errors, lol... it's just not working.

Comment: ooooh ok, in the fiddle you have a little bit more than what's in the post but yes that works perfectly. SPLENDID!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should be seeing errors in console because `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so `this.attr()` is invalid.

What you really want with your approach is to replace:

```
var item = this.attr('id').html().text();
```

With

```
var item = $(this).text();
```

Comment: is that the only thing you see wrong with the script?

Comment: `trim()` doesn't take arguments....it only removes whitespace. You need to use other string methods to shorten the string. That part is easy to research

Comment: yeah I went back and forth between that and substring, neither worked